# Silverlight и WCF. Ошибка Get..Async() метода

Tags: c#, mvvm, wcf, silverlight

Удаленный сервер возвратил ошибку: NotFound, Контракт службы имеет два метода, различие между только в том, что второй метод извлекает список строк по определенному полю name, вот код службы:

```
 public List<Logistic.Model.Object> GetProviders()
{
    var context = new LogisticEntities();
    var list = context.Objects.Where(o => o.TypeObject.description.ToLower().Contains("provider")).ToList();
    return list;
}
public List<string> GetProviderNames()
{
    var context = new LogisticEntities();
    var list = context.Objects.Where(o => o.TypeObject.description.ToLower().Contains("provider")).Select(c => c.name).ToList();
return list;
```

Проблема в том, что GetProviderNamesAsync() загружает данные, все хорошо, а вот вызов GetProvidersAsync() вызывает ошибку...
Вот ViewModel:

```
public TransportViewModel()
{
    LogisticServiceClient client = new LogisticServiceClient();
    client.GetProvidersCompleted += new EventHandler<GetProvidersCompletedEventArgs>(client_GetProvidersCompleted)
    client.GetProvidersAsync(); //здесь исключение

    client.GetProviderNamesCompleted += new EventHandler<GetProviderNamesCompletedEventArgs>(client_GetProviderNamesCompleted);
    client.GetProviderNamesAsync(); //но здесь все хорошо
}

private ObservableCollection<string> providerNames;
public ObservableCollection<string> ProviderNames
{
    get { return providerNames; }
    set
    {
        providerNames = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("ProviderNames");
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<LogisticService.Object> providers;
public ObservableCollection<LogisticService.Object> Providers
{
    get { return providers; }
    set
    {
        providers = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Providers");
    }
}

void client_GetProvidersCompleted(object sender, GetProvidersCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Providers = e.Result;
}

void client_GetProviderNamesCompleted(object sender, GetProviderNamesCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    ProviderNames = e.Result;
}
```

То есть получается, что вернуть список строк можно, а вот список объектов уже проблема...

Comment: Logistic.Model.Object - сериализуемый? Всмысле, в WCF не силен, но ему вроде надо знать, что и как передавать.

Comment: Нет, судя по всему в этом и проблема. Попробую серилизацию json сделать

Comment: на `Logistic.Model.Object` `DataContract` есть? Стандартные сериализуемые типы .NET вроде `List` или `string` ничего не требуется, а для кастомных нужно контракт писать и сериализацию.